# Why does pandas read_excel shift columns with each iteration?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying read a bunch of excel files (700+) and compile them into a single database using a for loop. However, each iteration of the for loop shifts the first four columns to the end of the data set in a bizarre repeating pattern. I'm not practiced in python, and I can't figure out what's causing this.

```
excel_files = glob.glob("/State Report_2020****308.xls")

list1 = [pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="Raw Data", usecols = "A:S", skiprows = 9, nrows=33-10) for filename in excel_files]
raw_data = pd.concat(list1, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

For example the data extracted from the first sheet looks like:

```
A B C ... Q R S
a b c ... q r s 
a b c ... q r s
a b c ... q r s
a b c ... q r s
```

Then Data from the second sheet is extracted, appended to the bottom of the data frame, and looks like:

```
A B C ... Q R S T U V W
e f g ... q r S a b c d
e f g ... q r S a b c d
e f g ... q r S a b c d
e f g ... q r S a b c d
```

Then data from the third sheet is iterated into the data frame, and looks like:

```
A B C ... Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA
e f g ... q r S         a b c d
e f g ... q r S         a b c d
e f g ... q r S         a b c d
e f g ... q r S         a b c d
```

This pattern repeats with every iteration shifting the first columns of data further to the right.

Comment: Could you share a runnable, reproducible example of the "bizarre repeating pattern"? We need more details to understand what might be the problem.

Comment: Is there a way I can provide the excel files for someone else to reproduce the pattern?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to include a minimal, reproducible sample of data and code which produces the unexpected result that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The error was from "skiprows = 9" as one of the pd.read_excel inputs. Row 9 was the column headers for the table. I thought if I left the headers in there, they would be added as a row with each subsequent iteration like:

```
A B C ... Q R S
a b c ... q r s 
a b c ... q r s
...............
A B C ... Q R S
a b c ... q r s 
a b c ... q r s
...............
A B C ... Q R S
a b c ... q r s 
a b c ... q r s
...............
```

Instead I left the headers in "skiprows = 8" and got the result I originally wanted.

```
A B C ... Q R S
a b c ... q r s 
a b c ... q r s
...............
a b c ... q r s 
a b c ... q r s
...............
a b c ... q r s 
a b c ... q r s
...............
```